# IIS rewrite - add '.html' to any URL's that don't have an extension

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup an `IIS` rewrite rule to add '.html' to URL's that don't have an extension, eg:

**Original URL:**    `www.domain.com/page`

**Rewrite to:** `www.domain.com/page.html`

And I want to ignore any URL's that have an extension (eg. if they are images or other files)

Does anybody know the rule that I would need to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked this out myself by modifying a rule that I had on another website:

```
<rule name="rewrite directories to html" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
</rule>
```